# React custom hook returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to start by saying that I'm relatively new to studying React and I'm trying to create a custom hook where I can insert the logic to toggle the visibility of a password entered into an input field.

The issue I'm encountering is that, as it seems, within the component where I import the hook, anything returned from it is always giving me undefined. My code is as follows:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineEye, AiOutlineEyeInvisible } from 'react-icons/ai';

export const usePasswordVisibility = () => {
    const [passwordIsVisible, setPasswordIsVisible] = useState(false);

    const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
        setPasswordIsVisible(!passwordIsVisible);
    };

    const PasswordIcon = passwordIsVisible
        ? AiOutlineEyeInvisible
        : AiOutlineEye;

    return {passwordIsVisible, togglePasswordVisibility, PasswordIcon};
};
```

```
import { usePasswordVisibility } from '../Utilities/usePasswordVisibility';

const { passwordIsVisible, togglePasswordVisibility, PasswordIcon } =
        usePasswordVisibility;

<input
    onChange={(ev) =>
        setUser({
            ...user,
            password: ev.target.value,
        })
    }
    className="w-full rounded-md shadow-lg focus:bg-emerald-100"
    type={passwordIsVisible ? 'text' : 'password'}
    name="password"
    id="password"
    autoComplete="new-password"
    placeholder="Password"
/>

<PasswordIcon
    onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
    className="absolute right-[4%] top-[28%] cursor-pointer"
/>
```

In this case, I'm receiving the error

Unexpected Application Error!
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `UserForm`.

and if I comment out  and try to console.log passwordIsVisible or togglePasswordVisibility, I get undefined.

Comment: Return value of custom hook should be an array (but it is not rule). Also can you please edit request to show how you call that custom hook? Many thanks.
`return [passwordIsVisible, togglePasswordVisibility, PasswordIcon];`

Comment: See [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring)

Comment: Hello, I've modified the request by adding the hook call and corrected the return to match how I'm actually doing it at the moment.

Comment: A custom hook is a function like any other hook. It should be called in order return the value.
`const { passwordIsVisible, togglePasswordVisibility, PasswordIcon } =
        usePasswordVisibility();`

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even realize that I wasn't invoking the function.